# Why is the second output printing a list of NONE instead of a sentence?Have I done any mistake?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, nlp, stop-words

the output keeps on giving me a list of NONE
[image]

Comment: please post the code and output as text, not as an image

Comment: actually thats what i tried to do but i could not submit the question because of error so i decided to take a screenshot

Comment: Which error?---

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1):

Your clean sentence function can return two things. If `stopwords` is set to true, returns sentence. If not, it returns the default value, `None`. Fix this loophole and you'll get your correct result.